# Using two roscreate-pkg packages and being able to read the src file code

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I have one package (lets call it a) and inside this is the CMakeLists.txt file, manifest.xml and a few .h and .cpp files of code that talk to each other in the src folder. My src file is starting to get a little big so ideally I want to have more than one package (such as one called b) that has its own CMakeLists.txt file, manifest.xml  and src file. What I want is the code in the src folder for package a to be able to communicate with the src folder for package b. I added the line:
`<depend package="a"/>`
to the manifest.xml in package b but I am unable to read the src code from package a.

Perhaps my way of thinking is wrong. If so, could you explain to me the best way to partition the code would be? If I am on the right track, what have I missed out?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/87576/using-two-roscreate-pkg-packages-and-being-able-to-read-the-src-file-code/) by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2013-10-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on 2013-10-06**:
Thanks for the reply. I do not have any cflags and Iflags in my manifest.xml for my package. (I used ros-create pkg). how to I get these?

**Comment by [jdorich](https://answers.ros.org/users/7496/jdorich/) on 2013-10-06**:
This ROS answer (http://answers.ros.org/question/33779/how-do-i-link-an-executable-with-library-in-other-package/) covers all the things you have to do.

**Comment by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on 2013-10-06**:
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See [this ROS answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/33779/how-do-i-link-an-executable-with-library-in-other-package/). You have to export cflags and lflags in package a in your case mentioned.

---

Originally posted by [jdorich](https://answers.ros.org/users/7496/jdorich/) with karma: 211 on 2013-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on 2013-10-06**:
Thank you!!